# Does BreezeSharp support view pattern?

Tags: breeze, breeze-sharp

Does BreezeSharp support functionality like grouping, sorting, filtering, and navigating a data collection that CollectionView supports?

The use case is similar to the following. A collection of employees for a parent company and it's child companies are retrieved. Based on the company name, the employees need to be filtered (and presented to the UI). Only one company and it's employees are shown at a time.

If Breeze does not support this, should I have my own CollectionView to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure I understand the question. The .NET CollectionView class can certainly be used in conjunction with any collection of Breeze.sharp entities. In addition, all nonscalar breeze navigation properties are live lists, so you won't need to manage the membership of these lists.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by live lists? Do you mean the client will lazy load the entities from the server if needed so a long running initial load of all the entities (all employees and all the companies) is not necessary. Coming back to the question, the CollectionView is to primarily support the filtering for the UI. The CollectionView can be directly mapped to the listcontrol for example, and have a filtered view.

Comment: No, a live list means that if you have a reference to the result of a navigation property of an entity, say the 'OrderDetails' property of an 'Order' entity, then any OrderDetail that is either queried or added to the EntityManager that also happens to 'belong' to that 'Order' will automatically be added to the previously referenced list.